# In-browser default selected text color - What is it?

Tags: html, css, browser

Supposing no CSS, javascript or other HTML trickery, how does the browser determine the color of the text and background for selected text?

For example, standard white background (`#FFFFFF` or `RGB=255,255,255`) with black text (`#000000` or `RGB=0,0,0`) when selected with invert the colors (i.e. `black background`, `white text`). How are other colors chosen? For example, when writing a question on this site, the right sidebar has an area "How to ask" with `background #FFEFC6` and `text #AE0000`, which when selected become `#3399FF` and `#FFFFFF` respectively.

I would like to know how this is determined (is there an algorithm or just defaults) and is this the same across browsers?

Comment: FYI, in my chrome on Windows the default selection background colour is `#3297fd`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd agree with Joshua that the colors come from the system, but I'd disagree about CSS, for example, [CSS-Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/wp-content/themes/CSS-Tricks-5/style.css):

```
::selection { background: #ffcc89; color: #222; }
::-moz-selection { background: #ffcc89; color: #222; }
```

For more info, see [Quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/selection.html) on selection styles.

Comment: Great. Confirmed: I've tinkered with the system settings and, in Windows Vista, "Selected Items" has a background and font setting. Other OS will, of course, differ. Thanks for the CSS tips.

Answer (score 2):

In my recall, the foreground and background colors are read from system colors and cannot be controlled by CSS.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that each operating/windowing system has its own algorithm. On many, you can select from a few different schemes. It will NOT be the same across all browsers.

For example, in Safari on my Mac, selecting black text on a white background results in a blue rectangle around black text.