# Name of color of selection highlight in CSS

Tags: html, css, colors

Thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16094931/816449) I know hex values of default colors of selection on different systems, and also know that you could set color of selected text or items using CSS 3.

But what I want is to highlight selection of other elements (in SVG) using that same color. Is it possible to make that color the same as system default? Does it have some name in CSS?

In other words: I want some element to have the same color as the text selection on that system. Is it possible?

Possible solution could be to set selection color in CSS for all the website to some value like `#3399FF`, but that is not possible in my case. I guess I'll just use hex constant, but wander if there is any name for such a color?

Comment: I would like to help you, but it is not clear to me what you want to do, could you include a visual example, what you have vs what you are looking for

Comment: @jtorrescr I edited the question. Hope now explanation is better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, after some research I have found that in CSS 2 there was colors called system colors ([W3C Recommendation](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/#css2-system)), and there is colors named `Highlight` and `HighlightText`. Which works in Firefox on Linux.

Also W3C says that the CSS2 System Color values have been deprecated in favor of the CSS3 UI ‘appearance’ property. But I could not found anything about that property using [link](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-ui/#appearance) that they provided.