# Determine browser's default text highlight color using JavaScript or Dart

Tags: javascript, html, css, browser, dart

The browser's default text highlight (selection) background color can be [overridden](https://css-tricks.com/overriding-the-default-text-selection-color-with-css/), e.g.:

```
::selection {
  background: #ffb7b7;
}
```

And [the color is browser/OS specific](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16094837/what-is-the-browser-default-background-color-when-selecting-text?lq=1). Is there a way to read the browser's default value using JavaScript or Dart?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would say that you can't.

Both `getComputedStyle(yourElement, '::selection').backgroundColor` and `getComputedStyle(yourElement, '::-moz-selection').backgroundColor` will return `transparent` as default value and browser won't override os's default.
*(Worth to be mentioned that if **you** set it to transparent, default os' value will be overriden*).

I don't think browsers have access to os default preferences, and if they do, they probably won't let any website access it it so easily.

Answer (score 2):

As described at https://stackoverflow.com/a/39543711/3273929, you can use CSS system colors: https://www.w3.org/TR/2010/PR-css3-color-20101028/#css2-system, although they are deprecated, they do work.

Comment: While `Background` and `Highlight` *do* work, neither seems to actually match what I'm seeing in Chrome on Ubuntu.